# javafx: double click on a blank row opens the previusly selected object

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Given a TableView, I need to detect the doubleclick in order to open a new window of the related object.

But if I select an object and than I click in a blank space of my tableview, it will open the object that I previously selected.

I've been looking around and everybody define an object row for the tableview and when the row is empty (`row.isEmpty()`) they solve the problem.

And so, my question is: can I do the same thing without specifying the rows of the TableView?

Here's the controller for my table:

I'm italian so some stuff is written in Italian (like object and variables name)
I highlighted the part that are important for the creation of the table with the following comment: /****part of the tableview****/

```
    package application;

    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
    import javafx.scene.image.Image;
    import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
    import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;



    public class ControllerListaTest implements Initializable,EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

        private final Image immagine1  = new Image("https://pa1.narvii.com/6360/8fcb3b5341f11cbb119ff7139350c6d1296b338d_hq.gif");
        private final Image immagine2  = new Image("http://www.peency.com/images/2015/10/04/vegeta-majin-gif.gif");
        private final Image immagine3  = new Image("https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11133/111334329/6132586-0162048443-9e374.gif");
    @FXML
    private Button bottone;
    //la creazione della tabella è stata fatta con scene builder le colonne sono state invece create direttamente dal file mostraopere.fxml
    /****creation of the table****/
    @FXML private TableView<Opera> tabella; //imposto il contenuto della tabella
    /****creation of the columns****/
    @FXML private TableColumn<Opera,ImageView> colonna1;//imposto il tipo della prima colonna
    @FXML private TableColumn<Opera,String> colonna2;//imposto il tipo della seconda colonna
    @FXML private TableColumn<Opera,String> colonna3;//imposto il tipo della terza colonna



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    /****setting the table ****/
        tabella.setMaxWidth(600);
        tabella.setMinWidth(600);
        colonna1.setMinWidth(200);
        colonna1.setMaxWidth(200);
        colonna2.setMinWidth(200);
        colonna2.setMinWidth(200);
        colonna3.setMinWidth(200);
        colonna3.setMinWidth(200);

        bottone.setOnAction(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(event.getSource()==bottone) {
            //creazione delle opere
            Opera opera = new Opera("Il SuperSayan","Giangiacomo Frizzantino",immagine1);
            Opera opera1 = new Opera("Goku è scarso ed ecco perchè","Pierpaolo stracazzi",immagine2);
            Opera opera2 = new Opera("mi piace la droga","Marzio Fannullone",immagine3);
            Opera opera3 = new Opera("10 cose positive della bestiality","Patrizio Fallo");
            //creazione del contenuto di un opera
            ContenutoOpera immagineuno = new ContenutoOpera(immagine1,opera,"1");
            ContenutoOpera immaginedue = new ContenutoOpera(immagine1,opera,"2");
            ContenutoOpera immaginetre = new ContenutoOpera(immagine1,opera,"3");
            ContenutoOpera immaginequattro = new ContenutoOpera(opera,"4");
            //caricamento dell contenuto di un opera nelle rispettive liste(Opere)
            opera.addImmagine(immagineuno);
            opera.addImmagine(immaginedue);
            opera.addImmagine(immaginetre);
            opera.addImmagine(immagineuno);
            opera.addImmagine(immaginedue);
            opera.addImmagine(immaginetre);
            opera.addImmagine(immagineuno);
            opera.addImmagine(immaginedue);
            opera.addImmagine(immaginetre);
            opera.addImmagine(immagineuno);
            opera.addImmagine(immaginedue);
            opera.addImmagine(immaginetre);
            opera.addImmagine(immagineuno);
            opera.addImmagine(immaginedue);
            opera.addImmagine(immaginedue);
            opera.addImmagine(immaginetre);
            opera.addImmagine(immagineuno);
            opera.addImmagine(immaginedue);
            opera.addImmagine(immaginetre);
            opera1.addImmagine(immaginetre);
            opera1.addImmagine(immaginetre);
            opera.addImmagine(immaginequattro);
            //indirizzo il contenuto delle colonne
            /****setting the column****/
            colonna1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Image"));
            colonna2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Opera"));
            colonna3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Autore"));
            //creo una lista di opere
            ObservableList<Opera> opere = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            //aggiungo le opere alla lista
            opere.add(opera);
            opere.add(opera1);
            opere.add(opera2);
            opere.add(opera3);
            //TEST
            System.out.println(opera.getLista().size() + " (numero di elementi in opera)");
/****retrive the elements of a list and add them to the table****/
            tabella.getItems().setAll(opere);
            /****resulted from the click of the table****/
            tabella.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {                
                   // System.out.println(tabella.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getNome());
                /****check the double click****
if(event.getClickCount() == 2){ 
                    if(tabella.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getAutore()!="")  //ricordarsi di fare il controllo per verificare che l'oggetto è di tipo ContenutoOpera
                    try {
                            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
                                    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("ciao label.fxml"));
                                    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();

                                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                                    stage.setScene(new Scene(root1)); 
                                    Controllerlabel controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
         /****passes the selected object to another controller**** 
                    controller.initData(tabella.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());        
                                    stage.show();
                            } catch(Exception e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                              }
                        }
                    }
                }

            );


        }

    }
    public void pressButton(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {               
        try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ciao label.fxml"));
                Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
                stage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
    }
```

Comment: May I ask why you wish to avoid `TableRow`s?

Comment: Because I don't have time to rethink the structure of the tableview and honestly I don't have the knowledge to do that

Comment: Using a `rowFactory` and adding the appropriate `EventHandler` shouldn't be too disruptive. I'll give an example to see if you like it.

Comment: There's a whole section of your code that is commented out (accidentally i guess). Please fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason double-clicking on an empty row causes you to open the last selected item is because you're adding the `EventHandler` to the `TableView`. When you click anywhere on the `TableView`, including empty rows, the `EventHandler` is invoked. What you want is a per-row `EventHandler` that checks if the row is empty or not. Also, since each `TableRow` has a reference to its item you don't have to use the `TableView`'s selection model. Here's an example:

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class Controller {

  @FXML
  private TableView<Object> table; // Using <Object> for example

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> onClick = this::handleTableRowMouseClick;
    table.setRowFactory(param -> {
      TableRow<Object> row = new TableRow<>();
      row.setOnMouseClicked(onClick);
      return row;
    });
  }

  private void handleTableRowMouseClick(MouseEvent event) {
    if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY && event.getClickCount() == 2) {

      // We know it will be a TableRow<Object> since that is the only kind
      // of object we added the EventHandler to.
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      TableRow<Object> row = (TableRow<Object>) event.getSource();

      if (!row.isEmpty() && row.getItem() != null) {
        displayItem(row.getItem());
        event.consume();
      }
    }
  }

  private void displayItem(Object item) {
    // This is where you'd put your code that opens the item in
    // its own Stage.
  }

}
```

In the example the `EventHandler` is shared with every `TableRow` created by the `rowFactory`. This is okay since we can get the source (i.e. the `TableRow` that was clicked on) by calling `MouseEvent.getSource()`. I split things up into more methods to make the code more readable/maintainable.

The example checks if the mouse button was the primary button. If you don't care which button was clicked twice then you can simply remove that check.

Comment: I have just seen your example and i have to ask you how can I fill the rows with the specific elements of an object .To have a better image of the table,it consist in 3 columns and each rows contain 3 specific attribute of the releted object and when i click a row it opens a new stage

Comment: @PurpleKiwi Using a custom `rowFactory` doesn't alter how the `TableColumn`s have been configured. In your code you already have `columnXXX.setCellValueFactory(...)` and this will still work.